# Regular expression match starting at the end of a Sublime Text "view"

Tags: python, regex, plugins, sublimetext2

I concocted the following regular expression, that is supposed to give me all text in the view that comes before the second to last `}`:

```
region = currentView.find("(?<=\\})[^\\}]+\\}[^\\}]*$", 0)
```

Sublime Text does not seem to think that `$` means "end of whatever is in the view." To be honest, I don't quite understand what Sublime Text thinks it means.

My regular expression seems to work, as shown here on [regexr.com](http://regexr.com?36r96).

I found a workaround for my particular cirmunstance that I can live with for the moment:

```
regions = currentView.find_all("\}")
    if len(regions) > 1:
        # stuff I am doing with regions[-2] goes here
```

but I would like to know if it is **possible** to match against the end of the view's content.

Comment: `$` in regex means "end of string". So is your end of view the end of the string ?

Comment: I don't know enough about how Sublime Text implements it's buffers. I guess what I am looking for is an *end of buffer*, and I assumed *end of string* would work...

Comment: If you want to construct a regex, you need to know some input you're expecting. You then elaborate a pattern. So can you provide us some input ? Also I don't seem to understand why you're using `\\}` ? Isn't `\}` enough if you want to match a literal `}` ?

Comment: @HamZa: I provided an example in the link to [regexr.com](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?36r96), for reasons of neatness and clarity, I didn't want to clutter up the body of the actual question, since my problem *appears* to be Sublime's API and not the actual regex. The regular expression above is in the form of a python string, which needs the `/` symbol to be escaped.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`$` at the end of a regex can mean either the end of line or the end of the input, depending on the engine and modifier flags that are passed in. A quick look at Sublime's doc show that it supports the `\z` boundary, which unequivocally means "the end of the input buffer". So try replacing your final `$` with `\z`, to see if that helps.

Comment: Brilliant! It does exactly what I want. May I ask where in Sublime's docs you found the answer? I did look there myself quite extensibly!

Comment: Here in [Sublime's doc](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/search_and_replace/search_and_replace_overview.html#regular-expressions) The very last sentence refer to the Boost syntax. Then, in Boost's documentation, we have: [Buffer Bundaries](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html#boost_regex.syntax.perl_syntax.buffer_boundaries)

Comment: Note that the address for the corresponding Sublime's documentation has changed: see [Sublime Text Community Documentation](https://docs.sublimetext.io/guide/usage/search-and-replace.html#regular-expressions).